# animated progress bar by script for IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, background

Please, help me. I need an advice in problem with progress bar in IE. It should be animated, as showed in http://www.webappers.com/progressBar/. 
I downloaded jquery.backgroundpos.js, but still it works weird for IE. In chrome it animates with horizontal direction, in IE - with vertical. How could this be? 
And the other problem - animation goes only for some period of time, wich we define. I need the cycle independet from time, just user aciton.

Comment: Absolutely easiest way and to avoid wasting precious time is to use a gif animation. It's really not worth the headache to try and get this to work properly in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler solution without any plugin.
HTML:

```
<div id="blank_bar"><div id="filled_bar"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#blank_bar{
     width: 100px; //barwith
     background:   //empty bar background
}

#filled_bar{
     width: 30%;   // completion percentage
     background:   // your background without repeat
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#filled_bar").css("width","newpercentage%");
```

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VxBhr/2/ (just replace background colors by images).

Comment: One more thing. If you want an animation during progress, use animate function of jQuery :-). And also have a look on http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is in jquery animation.

Comment: it animates horizontally in chrome, in explorer 8 - vertically... i am using jquery.backgroundpos.js : $('.progress-bar span').animate({'backgroundPosition':'100px 0px'}, 10000);

Answer (score 1):

You could show a fiddle of that or a live example for more help.

For the first problem, without looking at the code, remember that `background-position` takes 2 arguments `x px y px`. Could be that IE animates different is there only one direction is specified eg `background-position: -5px`